# Get content from a specific tag in Selenium and JAVA

Tags: java, selenium

i´m facing a little problem with the following,

Consider this code :

```
<div data-v-2f952c88="" class="text">
 <section data-v-3b70ad5b="" data-v-2f952c88="" data-content-provider="OTS" class="description__section">        
    SOMETHING
 </section>
</div>
<div data-v-1343242dd="" class="text">
 <section data-v-2232lfd="" data-v-3fgssder="" data-content-provider="HTB" class="description__section">
    SOMETING ELSE
  </section>
</div>
```

How can i extract in Java using Selenium all the content from all the tags "data-content-provider" present in the code , so in the end i can have a string like this

string result="OTS,HTB".

Thanks

Comment: What you've done so far?

Comment: You'd have to loop and use .get_attribute('data-content-provider') on your elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
// get all section elements
List<WebElement> sections = driver.findElements(By.tagName("section"));

// new empty list of strings
List<String> dataContentProviders = new ArrayList<String>();

// collect all the data-content-provider values to dataContentProviders 
for (WebElement section: sections) {
     dataContentProviders.add(section.getAttribute("data-content-provider");
}
```

Comment: As expected :-) Pls mark the asnwer as helpfull. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can refer below code to get the desired output :

```
List< WebElement > list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//section"));
for(WebElement l : list)
        {
            String text=l.getAttribute("data-content-provider");
            System.out.println(text);
        }
```

Comment: `List list = ...` ?